# How to convert a function with named arguments to a pure function?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, scoping

A function is defined with named arguments. How can this function be converted to a pure function that uses slots (`#`). As a simple example, how can the following:

```
f[x_]:=2x
```

be converted to:

```
f=(2#) &;
```

I need to have a simple command for this conversion regardless of the expression of the function f. This has useful applications because sometimes when a module is defined in such a way that it only recognizes functions defined by unnamed arguments, then functions defined by named arguments won't be recognized properly. The problem I'd like to resolve is for instance:
given non-pure functions f(x) and g(x), I need to turn f(g(x))=fg(x) into a pure function like fg[#].

Comment: `h = f[#] &` and `h /@ {1, Sqrt[2], 3/2, 2.4, 2 + 4 I}` gives `{2, 2 Sqrt[2], 3, 4.8, 4 + 8 I}`.

Comment: many thanks for the helpful tip. The problem I'd like to resolve is for instance:
given non-pure functions f(x) and g(x), I need to turn f(g(x))=fg(x) into a pure function like fg[#].

Comment: Are you looking for `(f@*g)@x`? Look up `Composition`.

Comment: Similar to [your other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282227/pure-functions-failing-in-algebra), you could use `fg = Evaluate[f[g[#]]] &`, if using the evaluated expression `f[g[#]]` presents no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way (but result depends on `f` and `g`):

```
fFN = f[#] &
fg = f[g[#]] &
```

Risky way (evaluates body of `f` and `g` but result is independent of them):

```
f = Evaluate[f[#]] &
fg = Evaluate[f[g[#]]] &
```

Complicated way that deals with arbitrarily many `Pattern[v, Blank[]]` arguments and does not evaluate the body of the function:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
f[x_] := 2 x;
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + a y^3;

singleDVToPureFunctionRule =
  {Verbatim[HoldPattern][
       _[x : Verbatim[Pattern][_, Blank[]] ..]
       ] :> 
     body_} :>
   (body & /.
     Thread[
      Thread[HoldPattern[{x}][[All, All, 1]]] -> 
       Array[Slot, Length@{x}]
      ]);

x = 9; y = -7; a = 3;
Replace[DownValues[f], singleDVToPureFunctionRule]
Replace[DownValues[g], singleDVToPureFunctionRule]
(*
  2 #1 &
  #1^2 + a #2^3 &
*)
```